# How to get the current class name in Java with log4j

Tags: java, log4j

am using log4j for logging, in order to get the class name of the of the respective methods while executing, i got some common method which uses SecurityManager to get the class name, but i dont want to use SecurityManager, is their any other way to get the class name during runtime. Also i dont want to write the code(`MyClass.getClassName`) to get the classname in each and every class.

```
class log extends SecurityManager {

public String getClassName() {
        return getClassContext()[3].getName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution for static logger:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass());
```

Answer (score 4):

For the full name (with package):

```
this.getClass().getName();
```

For the name of the class (just class name and no more):

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of receiving the class name, you can also receive a `Logger` with the class object itself:

```
public static Logger getLogger(Class clazz)
```

This is how it's used:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger(java.lang.Class)

Comment: could you provide a working code using above snippet. I mean the exact code as should be used. Tx

Answer (score 2):

you could add the `%l` to your [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) in the appender configuration to get the calling class of your log statement.

Comment: hii, my log4j property file is below, can you guide where to make change.. #Console Log Appender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}\:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.Target=System.out

Comment: Add it in your pattern at a place you like. This should work:
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}\:%L - %l - %m%n

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need the class name of the class that is calling your log class?

Try this:

```
StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[3];
```

Comment: Hii, thanks for reply this worked.. one more issue is am not getting line numbers properly pls chk the console info below.. it always shows 95..18:54:20,410  INFO CreateRequisitionTest:95 - <==iONTest
18:54:46,010  INFO BaseTest:95 - ==>getDriver() ::Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way too:

```
private static final String CLASS_NAME = MyClass.class.getName();

log.debug(new LogRecord(CLASS_NAME," Success = "+isSuccess));
```